# Seaborn warning message

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, data-analysis

When I'm using the parameter *hue* in any plot that receives it, my notebook keeps showing a warning that poluates my visualizations. Take the code for example:

```
category_labels = ["Category A", "Category B"]
data = np.concatenate([np.random.randn(500), np.random.randn(500) + 3])
hue_labels = np.array([category_labels[0]] * 500 + [category_labels[1]] * 500)

sns.kdeplot(x=data, hue=hue_labels, common_norm=False, fill=True, palette="husl")

plt.show()
```

After running the code, the message below is shown:

```
C:\Users\brian.oliveira\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\seaborn\_base.py:949: FutureWarning: When grouping with a length-1 list-like, you will need to pass a length-1 tuple to get_group in a future version of pandas. Pass `(name,)` instead of `name` to silence this warning.
```

Can anyone help, please?

I've tried to pass a different method to 'hue' but it didn't worked.

Comment: Thanks, @JohanC! I checked the issue and it addresses my case. Altough it's not an error, it bugs my notebooks with those warning red boxes.

Comment: @JohanC, I updated the lib and it was fixed! Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

The warning is caused by a change in [Pandas 2.2.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v2.2.0.html).  Michael Waskom [just released seaborn 0.13.2](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew/v0.13.2.html) which gets rid of the warning.